# Making a widget that is sticky to East, West, and South in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, sticky

I'm currently working on an application on Tkinter, and I want one of my grid widgets to be sticky in all the directions except North? So far, this is the code that I've put in, but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
StatusBar.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=9, pady=1.25, sticky=SEW)
```

I've tried rearranging S, E, and W in all possible configurations, but when I try running the program, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'SEW' is not defined
```

Can someone help me out with this? It would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Should be `sticky='ew')` and inside a own `Frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the literal string "sew". There's no need to use a constant.

```
StatusBar.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=9, pady=1.25, sticky="sew")
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can just use ,

> StatusBar.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=9, pady=1.25, sticky=S+E+W)